# Windows BATCH .bat Проблема с модификаторами

Tags: windows, bat, dos

Есть рабочий скрипт

```
echo "--------START PREPARE----------"

reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

if %OS%==32BIT set pkzippath="%ProgramFiles%\PKWARE\PKZIPC\pkzipc.exe"
if %OS%==64BIT set pkzippath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PKWARE\PKZIPC\pkzipc.exe"

set filenamedate=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%


for %%a in (%8) do set newfilename=%%~da%%~pa%%~na_%filenamedate%%%~xa
for %%a in (%9) do set pDIR=%%~sa
for %%a in (%pDIR%) do set pDIR2=%%~pa
for %%a in (%pDIR2:~0,-1%) do set pPN=%%~na

echo "--------DONE PREPARE-----------"
echo "--------START ARCHIVING--------"

%pkzippath% %1=%2 %3=%4 %5 %6=%7 %newfilename% %9

echo "--------ARCHIVING DONE---------"

echo "--------COPY TO DRIVE----------"
echo "PROJECT NAME: %pPN%"
echo "ARCH NAME: %newfilename%"
echo "DESTINATION: ХХХХХХХХХ"
echo "LOGIN: %login% PASSWORD:%passw%"
net use O: \\10.ХХ.ХХ.ХХ\diskW /user:ХХХХ\%login% %passw%
xcopy %newfilename% "O:\ХХХХХХХХХ\%pPN%\" /Y
net use O: /delete /Y
echo "--------COPY DRIVE DONE--------"
```

К его работой нет никаких проблем. Но вот только я оборачиваю его в **IF блок** то, часть с изменением имени файла и получением имени папки перестает работать.

```
for %%a in (%8) do set newfilename=%%~da%%~pa%%~na_%filenamedate%%%~xa
for %%a in (%9) do set pDIR=%%~sa
for %%a in (%pDIR%) do set pDIR2=%%~pa
for %%a in (%pDIR2:~0,-1%) do set pPN=%%~na
```

В этих переменных просто пусто. Почему? есть другой способ получать по отдельным переменным имя файла, расширение, последнюю папку из пути?

Вот пример параметров передающихся в bat файл:

```
-attributes=all -mask=none -add -directories=current "P:tests\sg.zip" "sg\*.*"
```

P.S. Пример, как оборачиваю в блок IF:

```
echo "--------START PREPARE----------"

reg Query "HKLM\Hardware\Description\System\CentralProcessor\0" | find /i "x86" > NUL && set OS=32BIT || set OS=64BIT

if %OS%==32BIT set pkzippath="%ProgramFiles%\PKWARE\PKZIPC\pkzipc.exe"
if %OS%==64BIT set pkzippath="%ProgramFiles(x86)%\PKWARE\PKZIPC\pkzipc.exe"

set filenamedate=%date:~-4%-%date:~3,2%-%date:~0,2%

if %5 == -add (
for %%a in (%8) do set newfilename=%%~da%%~pa%%~na_%filenamedate%%%~xa
for %%a in (%9) do set pDIR=%%~sa
for %%a in (%pDIR%) do set pDIR2=%%~pa
for %%a in (%pDIR2:~0,-1%) do set pPN=%%~na

echo "--------DONE PREPARE-----------"
echo "--------START ARCHIVING--------"

%pkzippath% %1=%2 %3=%4 %5 %6=%7 %newfilename% %9

echo "--------ARCHIVING DONE---------"

echo "--------COPY TO DRIVE----------"
echo "PROJECT NAME: %pPN%"
echo "ARCH NAME: %newfilename%"
echo "DESTINATION: ХХХХХХХХХ"
echo "LOGIN: %login% PASSWORD:%passw%"
net use O: \\10.ХХ.ХХ.ХХ\diskW /user:ХХХХ\%login% %passw%
xcopy %newfilename% "O:\ХХХХХХХХХ\%pPN%\" /Y
net use O: /delete /Y
echo "--------COPY DRIVE DONE--------"
)
```

Comment: *Но вот только я оборачиваю его в IF блок* где именно и как именно это делается, нам предлагается догадаться? ну и почитайте на всякий случай про delayedexpansion...

Comment: Исправил. Про DelayedExpansion читаю, пока не совсем понятно, что с этими знаниями делать.

Comment: Чтобы не мучаться, сделайте просто: `IF NOT %5 == -add GOTO метка`, а метку соответственно расположите после блока.

Comment: Спасибо большое, помогло. Но почему не работает вариант выше так и не понял(

Comment: Ну Вы же прочитали про DelayedExpansion - когда разберётесь, поймёте. Кстати, эксперименты очень помогают процессу понимания.... заодно и про Set Local кусочек не пропустите - оно из той же бочки.